# Unable to Draw Triangles Through glDrawElements in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to draw a procedural sphere referenced [here](http://www.ashley-mills.com/Home/Blog/Entries/2009/4/16_How_to_draw_a_sphere_in_3D____.html).

I modified it a bit so that I can use the glDrawElements method of OpenGL ES 2.0

Here's my version of createSphere:

```
GLfloat sphereVerticies[10000]={0.0};
GLubyte triangleIndices[15000]={0};

int createSphere (GLfloat spherePoints[], GLubyte triangleIndices[], GLfloat fRadius, GLfloat step)
{
    int points = 0;

    GLfloat uStep = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS (step);
    GLfloat vStep = uStep;

    unsigned long index=0;

    for (GLfloat u = 0.0f; u <= (2 * M_PI); u += uStep) 
    {
        for (GLfloat v = -M_PI_2; v <= M_PI_2; v += vStep) 
        {               
            triangleIndices[index++]=points;
            triangleIndices[index++]=points+1;
            triangleIndices[index++]=points+2;
            triangleIndices[index++]=points+2;
            triangleIndices[index++]=points+3;
            triangleIndices[index++]=points;

            points++;
            spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v) * cosf(u);             // x
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v) * sinf(u);       // y
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v);                 // z

            points++;
            spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v) * cosf(u + uStep);             // x
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v) * sinf(u + uStep);       // y
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v);                         // z              

            points++;
            spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * cosf(u);                  // x
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * sinf(u);            // y
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v + vStep);                      // z

            points++;
            spherePoints[(points - 1) * 3] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * cosf(u + uStep);           // x
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 1] = fRadius * cosf(v + vStep) * sinf(u + uStep);     // y
            spherePoints[((points - 1) * 3) + 2] = fRadius * sinf(v + vStep);                       // z

        }
    }        
    return points;
}
```

In SetupGL I have:

```
..
glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
..
..
glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

 numPoints=createSphere(sphereVerticies, triangleIndices, 30.0f, 20.0f);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(sphereVerticies), sphereVerticies, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_indexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, _indexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleIndices), triangleIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    // New lines (were previously in draw)
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);        
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) sphereVerticies);

glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
```

and finally in drawInRect:

```
glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);   
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (int)(numPoints*1.5), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

Now what am I doing wrong here? I don't see any visual output. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can see two things:

`glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) sphereVerticies);`

the last argument there should be `0`, since the vertices are already buffered and bound in the VBO.

[OpenGL ES - glVertexAttribPointer documentation](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glVertexAttribPointer.xml)

> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_ARRAY_BUFFER target (see glBindBuffer) while a generic vertex attribute array is specified, pointer is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store...

And,

`glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (int)(numPoints*1.5), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);`

you should use `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` because you have more than 255 vertices.

---

As for the indices, this is how you index them:

```
                 (0,1,2)        (2,3,0)
 2       3      2              2       3
 o-------o      o              o-------o
 |       |      | \            |     /
 |       |  =>  |   \          |   /
 |       |      |     \        | /
 o-------o      o-------o      o
 0       1      0       1      0
```

So, from this chart we can see two problems:

1) The triangles do not close up the polygon

2) Notice the winding, the first triangle is CCW, the second CW.

Try this code:

```
        triangleIndices[index++]=points;
        triangleIndices[index++]=points+1;
        triangleIndices[index++]=points+2;
        triangleIndices[index++]=points+3;
        triangleIndices[index++]=points+2;
        triangleIndices[index++]=points+1;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out two issues, now it shows some output but it still is not correct. The normal of every alternate triangle is opposite. So I see fragmentation in drawing. Is there something wrong with how I'm assigning values to triangleIndices array?

Also I'll appreciate if you can suggest a better way of drawing. The method above does not draw all the rectangles of same size, rather the sphere has north pole and south pole where triangles are smaller. This might cause problem in texturing.

Comment: I can only see the sphere from outside. My requirement was to see sphere from inside it. It seems to be the problem of normals now. Will I have to reverse something?
BTW, is there a way to discuss these things in real time? :)

Also, I have another question, but it will be appropriate to post that in a separate thread. Will wait for your answer there as well.

Comment: Either flip the indices (i.e.: change the winding to CW) : (0,1,2) => (2,1,0) and (3,2,1) => (1,2,3) - or keep face culling disabled.

Comment: I changed to wireframe through GL_LINE_STIP. It shows a line connecting north pole to the south pole. Why is this unwanted line showing?

Comment: Looks like the sphere generation code produces a degenerate triangle joining the poles together. Does the same happen for the original version of the code?

Comment: Yes, it happens for original version of code too. Not sure why. I downloaded their sample code, that shows wireframe by default, and it has this central line. That's not visible when we draw triangles, but these unwanted vertices will cause trouble in texturing too., and I'm not sure which ones are causing this line.
Since you have much experience, it might be easier for you to locate the bug. :)

Comment: Hey arul. Thanks for your support so far. Just one question have in mind still. 
In your answer you say:
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid *) sphereVerticies);

the last argument there should be 0, since the vertices are already buffered and bound in the VBO.
What do you mean by that? I can see Apple's examples binding the buffer AND also passing buffer's address. See:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html

Comment: In the example they pass in the result of the `offsetof` macro, which returns the byte offset of the given member in the struct. Read the quote from OpenGL's documentation in my post. They store vertex position and color in single buffer, so they need to hint OpenGL as to how to read back the attributes from single buffer. This technique is known as interleaving.

Comment: Also note the quote right above the code snippet you linked to: `The key difference in Listing 9-3 is that the parameters to the glVertexPointer and glColorPointer functions no longer point to the vertex arrays. Instead, each is an offset into the vertex buffer object.`